# variable not defined in a switch case statement

Tags: c++, scope, switch-statement, declaration

Here is my switch case statement. The compiler keeps stating `totalShare` is not defined even though it's defined in case 1. I'm a beginner with C++ and just started to learn about stack.

```cpp
switch (option)
{
    case 1:
    {
        string newStock;
        double share;
        double price;

        cout << "Enter a new stock: " ;
        cin >> newStock;

        cout << "Enter a number of shares: " ;
        cin >> share;

        cout << "Enter price [for that number of shares]:  " ;
        cin >> price;

        //share x price
        double sharePrice = share * price;

        //add to stack
        newStockStack.push(sharePrice);

        //total share
        double totalShare;
        totalShare += share;
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        //calculate stacks
        double theTotal;
        while (!newStockStack.empty())
        {
            theTotal += newStockStack.top();
            newStockStack.pop();
            return theTotal;
        }
        // FORMULA
        //((every share x price)+ (every share x price)) / total number of shares

        double LifoPrice;
        LifoPrice = (theTotal / totalShare);
        cout << "The Lifo price for the stock is: " << LifoPrice << endl;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: variables declared inside case are available only in this scope, so you have to declare it outside switch to be able to use it in both cases (but keep in mind that if you go to case 2 it wont run code from case 1, so there will be no value)

Comment: `totalShare` is defined only within the scope (defined by `{}`) for case `1`.   It does not exist in the scope for case `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double totalShare;` is present inside the **"case 1" block**

That means, `totalShare` is local to that block i.e. its scope is within case 1 only and it is not visible outside that block.

But then you have `LifoPrice = (theTotal / totalShare);` inside the **"case 2" block**. That is why, your compiler complains that **`totalShare` is not defined** (within the case 2 block).

**Solution:**

Define that variable inside such a scope that would allow its usage wherever you want. In this case, since you need that variable within multiple case blocks, consider declaring that variable outside the switch statement. Because it is a good practice to limit the scope of the variables, if you need that variable only inside the switch statement then you can declare it inside the switch statement but before all the case blocks that need `totalShare`.

Comment: To be clear: it's not the `case` that gives it local scope, it's the `{...}` that follows the `case 1:`. Those braces define a local scope. A `case` statement by itself does not create a scope. Without them, the name would be visible later, and that leads to its own set of problems; don't remove them. +1.

Comment: @PeteBecker Of course, I knew that terminology would be a problem. That's why I had named those blocks as "case 1" and "case 2" in double inverted commas :P +1

Answer (score 1):

The variable `totalShare` is declared in the block scope under the label `case 1:`.

```
case 1:
{
    //...

    //total share
    double totalShare;
    totalShare += share;
    break;
}
```

So in the block scope under the label `case 2:` it is not visible

```
LifoPrice = (theTotal / totalShare);
```

You may declare the variable before any case label.

Or if the compiler supports the C++ 17 Standard then you may declare it in the switch statement.